# Action can't update view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

there is a question when i ues `react`,

1.

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';  
    let change = (state, action) => {
        switch(action.type) {
            case 'change':
                return {
                    value: action.value
                }
                break;
            default:
                return {
                     value: 'default'
                 };
        }
    }
    let combineReducer = combineReducers({
        change

    })
    export default combineReducer;
```

---

2.

```
export default (state, action)=>{
        switch (action.type) {
        case 'change':
            return {
                value: action.value
            }
            break;
        default:
            return {
                value: 'default'
            };
    }
}
```

---

> What are the differences?
>
> when i ues the No.1, the view
>    can't update. but the No.2 can do it, why?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `combineReducer`，the state-tree will be **nested**. For instance, your state tree is `{ value: '' }` in NO.2, but in NO.1, it's `{ change: { value: '' } }`.

So you should change your `mapStateToProps` from `state => ({ value: state.value })` to `state => ({ value: state.change.value })`.

It's easy to understand: when you combine many reducers, a key is needed to mark each reducer.

http://7xinjg.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/combined-redux.png